# Frequency change irregular time series

Tags: r, time

I have an irregular time series where the frequency should be 2 sec but it's occasionally 4  seconds. When I try to change the time step in minutes I have an error... the desired output should be

```
"2017-04-01 00:03:00 5.6179"
```

Only the full minute should be displayed but instead I got two values

```
DateTime<-c("2017-04-01 00:02:38 CEST", "2017-04-01 00:02:40 CEST","2017-04-01 00:02:42 CEST",
   "2017-04-01 00:02:46 CEST","2017-04-01 00:02:48 CEST" ,"2017-04-01 00:02:50 CEST" ,
   "2017-04-01 00:02:52 CEST","2017-04-01 00:02:54 CEST","2017-04-01 00:02:56 CEST" ,
   "2017-04-01 00:02:58 CEST","2017-04-01 00:03:00 CEST", "2017-04-01 00:03:02 CEST")

Time<-as.POSIXct(DateTime)
set.seed(1)
Values<-runif(12,5,8)
df<-data.frame(Time, Values)
library(xts)
dfSeconds <- xts(df[,2], order.by=as.POSIXct(df[,1], format='%y/%m/%d %H:%M:  %S'))
dfMinutes<-to.minutes(dfSeconds,OHLC=FALSE,indexAt="startof")
dfMinutes
                    [,1]
2017-04-01 00:02:58 6.692016
2017-04-01 00:03:02 7.518400
```

Not sure how to solve the issue in the huge data frame.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do not want to round, but only remove the seconds, this could help, removing also the useless column:

```
df$Time <- floor_date(df$Time,unit ="minute")
```

But if you want to have only the row with the minute, you can try this:

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
dat <- df %>%
       filter(second(Time)==0) %>%  # filter only the minutes with 00 seconds
       data.frame()
```

Then convert to an `xts` object:

```
library(xts)
xts(dat[,2], order.by=as.POSIXct(dat[,1], format='%y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S'))
                        [,1]
2017-04-01 00:03:00 5.617924
```

This mean that you'll not have data if the seconds are all different from 00, but looking at your example, it seems you need that.

Comment: Thank you for the answer but I want to have just the minute frequency so from all the data the output should be just the value at the exact full minute ""2017-04-01 00:03:00 5.6179""

Comment: You are welcome! Sorry I do not understand, could you point out what on the column Time_rounded is wrong? Or simply you need two columns, so that is the mistake? However I've edited, maybe you mean that.

Comment: It's acctually just changing the time step of the data on 1 minutes interval and deleting all the other values so the new data frame should have only a single value:""2017-04-01 00:03:00 5.6179""

Comment: Edited, a bit hacky, but it seems to fit, let me know.

Comment: Works perfectly fine though need to check it on huge dataset

Comment: Is there any simple way to change the frequency of data? Let's say from 1 min to 5 min?

Comment: I think that if you want a regular steps like 00, 05, 10, 15... you can work with the filter, something like `filter(minute(time) %in% c(0,5,10,15,20,25,30,35,40,45,50,55), second == 0 )`.